# Javascript - How to return Nan when looking at a list of number

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

lets say I have a function that takes in a number and does something to it such as multiplication. If a string or something other than a number is passed into it how would I return NaN with the function

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript’s `isNaN()` function.

```js
 if(isNaN(num1)){
    //is not a number
 }else{
    //is a number
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type of the variable passed to the function using [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

```
function doSomething(num) {
    if(typeof num != "number") {
        return NaN;
    }
  
    return num * 5;
}

console.log(doSomething(1));
console.log(doSomething("asdf"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [0,1,'foo',3,4,'bar123', NaN]

arr.map(i => {
  if (Number.isNaN(i)) {
    console.log(i, 'Number NaN')
  } else if (isNaN(i)) {
    console.log(i, 'NaN')
  }
})
```